# R: Non-onerous method of getting CrossTable (gmodels) results nicely formatted (html) into markdown document

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, crosstab, r-markdown

the code below

````
---
title: "Example"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
require(datasets)
data(esoph)
require(knitr, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
kable(table(esoph$agegp, esoph$alcgp),
caption = "Some sample")
```
````

Generates this pleasant table:
[image: Table example - kable and table]

I like more the results generated by the `CrossTable` function from the `gmodels` package, where I have a lot flexibility to introduce interesting summaries:

```
> CrossTable(esoph$agegp, esoph$alcgp, digits = 1, prop.r = FALSE, prop.t = FALSE, chisq = FALSE,
+ prop.chisq = FALSE)
   Cell Contents 
|-------------------------|
|                       N | 
|           N / Col Total | 
|-------------------------|

========================================================
               esoph$alcgp
esoph$agegp    0-39g/day   40-79   80-119   120+   Total
--------------------------------------------------------
25-34                  4       4        3      4      15
                     0.2     0.2      0.1    0.2        
--------------------------------------------------------
35-44                  4       4        4      3      15
                     0.2     0.2      0.2    0.1        
--------------------------------------------------------
45-54                  4       4        4      4      16
                     0.2     0.2      0.2    0.2        
--------------------------------------------------------
55-64                  4       4        4      4      16
                     0.2     0.2      0.2    0.2        
--------------------------------------------------------
65-74                  4       3        4      4      15
                     0.2     0.1      0.2    0.2        
--------------------------------------------------------
75+                    3       4        2      2      11
                     0.1     0.2      0.1    0.1        
--------------------------------------------------------
Total                 23      23       21     21      88
                     0.3     0.3      0.2    0.2
========================================================
```

What I would like to achieve is to use the results generated via the `CrossTable` in the same manner as I'm using the table results. In particular, I'm interested in forcing those results in the `kable` so it formats nicely. I browser through StackOverflow and came across the relevant discussions on *[Printing cross-tabulations in knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516471/printing-nice-cross-tabulations-in-knitr)* or introducing *[counts and percentages in xtables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444440/counts-percentages-in-xtable-sweave-r-cross-tabulations?rq=1)*. The solutions discussed there appear to be elaborate. In effect, I would only like to move my `CrossTable` output to an object that `kable` can understand reformat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give a try to the `pander` [general S3 method](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#generic-pander-method) instead of `kable`:

```
> pander(CrossTable(esoph$agegp, esoph$alcgp, digits = 1))

------------------------------------------------------------
   &nbsp;     0-39g/day   40-79    80-119    120+    Total  
------------ ----------- -------- -------- -------- --------
**25-34**\    &nbsp;\    &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\ 
    N\           4\        4\       3\       4\       15\   
 Row(%)\        27%\      27%\     14%\      5%\      17%   
 Column(%)      27%\      17%\     19%\      3%\            
                 20%       17%       5%       5%            

**35-44**\    &nbsp;\    &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\ 
    N\           4\        4\       4\       3\       15\   
 Row(%)\        27%\      20%\     19%\      5%\      17%   
 Column(%)      27%\      17%\     14%\      5%\            
                 27%       17%       5%       3%            

**45-54**\    &nbsp;\    &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\ 
    N\           4\        4\       4\       4\       16\   
 Row(%)\        25%\      25%\     19%\      5%\      18%   
 Column(%)      25%\      17%\     19%\      5%\            
                 25%       17%       5%       5%            

**55-64**\    &nbsp;\    &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\ 
    N\           4\        4\       4\       4\       16\   
 Row(%)\        25%\      25%\     19%\      5%\      18%   
 Column(%)      25%\      17%\     19%\      5%\            
                 25%       17%       5%       5%            

**65-74**\    &nbsp;\    &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\ 
    N\           4\        3\       4\       4\       15\   
 Row(%)\        27%\      27%\     19%\      3%\      17%   
 Column(%)      20%\      17%\     19%\      5%\            
                 27%       13%       5%       5%            

 **75+**\     &nbsp;\    &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\ 
    N\           3\        4\       2\       2\       11\   
 Row(%)\        27%\      18%\     10%\      5%\      12%   
 Column(%)      36%\      13%\     10%\      2%\            
                 18%       17%       3%       2%            

   Total        23\        23\      21\      21\      88\   
                 26%       26%      24%      24%            
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Although it's not currently supporting suppressing row percentages, but you can suppress column or total percentages natively with `CrossTable`:

```
> pander(CrossTable(esoph$agegp, esoph$alcgp, digits = 1, prop.c = FALSE, prop.t = FALSE, chisq = FALSE, prop.chisq = FALSE))

------------------------------------------------------------
   &nbsp;     0-39g/day   40-79    80-119    120+    Total  
------------ ----------- -------- -------- -------- --------
**25-34**\    &nbsp;\    &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\ 
    N\           4\        4\       3\       4\       15\   
   Row(%)        27%       27%      20%      27%      17%   

**35-44**\    &nbsp;\    &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\ 
    N\           4\        4\       4\       3\       15\   
   Row(%)        27%       27%      27%      20%      17%   

**45-54**\    &nbsp;\    &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\ 
    N\           4\        4\       4\       4\       16\   
   Row(%)        25%       25%      25%      25%      18%   

**55-64**\    &nbsp;\    &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\ 
    N\           4\        4\       4\       4\       16\   
   Row(%)        25%       25%      25%      25%      18%   

**65-74**\    &nbsp;\    &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\ 
    N\           4\        3\       4\       4\       15\   
   Row(%)        27%       20%      27%      27%      17%   

 **75+**\     &nbsp;\    &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\  &nbsp;\ 
    N\           3\        4\       2\       2\       11\   
   Row(%)        27%       36%      18%      18%      12%   

   Total        23\        23\      21\      21\      88\   
                 26%       26%      24%      24%            
------------------------------------------------------------
```

About row-percentage support, please add a comment at the [related issue](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/pull/140), and I am pretty sure @RomanTsegelskyi will be happy to fix this.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for showing the interest. I tried your code but the results are slightly messy (problem `CrossTable` introducing additional rows at the beginning). Screenshots: [1](http://cl.ly/image/0l0m13432G1z),[2](http://cl.ly/image/2Q2m2q3I0y3R).

Comment: @Konrad I've just realized you are suing `gmodels::CrossTable` while `pander` supports `descr::CrossTable`. AFAIK it works similarly, so loading `descr` instead of `gmodels` should resolve this issue. If not, then probably you are using the CRAN version of `pander`, can you please give a try with the most [recent version](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#installation) with `devtools`?

Comment: Thank you Sir! It works like a charm, [preview](http://rpubs.com/konradedgar/tablesexample).

Comment: Using WINDOWS PANDOC to convert the rmd file shown in this section, I have had trouble getting horizontal and vertical lines to isolate each cell as given in any gmodels CrossTable output. This is what happens after I run PANDOC from the rmd file in this section:

* If I create a DOCX file and open it with Libra Office, I get the lines I want on the screen, but not when I print the file.
* If I open the same DOCX file in the Office 16 Word, I do not get the lines.
* If I create an HTML file, I also do not get the lines.

Is there another easy way to get the lines I want?