# Error in as.data.frame.default(x): cannot coerce class ‘"htest"’ in a data.frame

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, quarto

I have this error `Error in as.data.frame.default(x): cannot coerce class ‘"htest"’ in a data.frame` in the following code example (my data set has about 30.000 cases, here are just the first ten to demonstrate my problem)

My goal is to print the crosstable created with `CrossTable` nicely in Markdown.

```
library(knitr)
library(gmodels)
#dataframe with variables dissat_r and clusterType
dissat_r <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
clusterType <- c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4)
ds <- data.frame(dissat_r, clusterType)
tble <- gmodels::CrossTable(ds$dissat_r, ds$clusterType, prop.c = FALSE, prop.t = FALSE, expected = TRUE, fisher = TRUE)

#use kable for a markdown-table
crstbl <- kable(tble, "markdown")
```

I think the problem is that there are things in `tble` that `kable()` can't work with. I'm open to other ways of making a markdown table from the crosstab.

I've tried other crosstab-functions, but the result didn't satisfy me.
Ideally, the table should also output Chi² etc., similar to what the `stargazer()` function does for regressions.

Comment: The output of `CrossTable` is a list of different structures. If you want it output in a pretty table, then that conversion has to be defined somewhere. Are you asking whether there exists some function to define a pretty output for `CrossTable`?

Comment: Yes, this would be help (some function to define a pretty output in markdown).

Comment: In that case, your question is either a request for external libraries / functions to do this, which may not exist, and in any case is off-topic on Stack Overflow, or a request for someone to write an implementation, which is too broad a question for SO. "Nicely" printing the output is a matter of opinion and taste. You may need to be a bit more specific and narrow your question down.

Comment: Where do I have ask if I am looking for a function, that print crosstables in Markdown?
"Nicely" is not specific, of course. I need the table itself (with frequencies and row/column percentages) and then Chi², d.f. (degree of freedom), the p value and the Fisher test.

Comment: I understand your requirements, but I guess my point is that _someone_ would need to write a function to convert this specific input into the specific output that you want (since as far as I can tell, such an implementation doesn't currently exist). Of course it is possible, but it would be a significant amount of work, and implementing a new feature / function is not what Stack Overflow is for. You would probably need to write this yourself, by extracting the various components of `tble` and putting them into a data frame.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But this is not an option for me. It would help me to know the existing functions that at least partially meet my requirements.

Comment: Well, it's a fairly specific requirement, so I suspect even the season R users here would need to do a search to find anything appropriate. Have you looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27529575/r-non-onerous-method-of-getting-crosstable-gmodels-results-nicely-formatted)?

Comment: No, I didn't. But that works. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R: Non-onerous method of getting CrossTable (gmodels) results nicely formatted (html) into markdown document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27529575/r-non-onerous-method-of-getting-crosstable-gmodels-results-nicely-formatted)